# SSRS web service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created an SSRS report in Visual studio and deployed the report to the web service url, when i go on the url the web service looks like the below and not the nice dashboard like that attached

any ideas would be appreciated?

The report still works if i click on the hyperlink
[image: Webservice]
Thanks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/media/ssrsportal.png?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Just go to `http://servername/Reports`

Comment: As WEI_DBA said, there are two different URLs that access your report server.  One will lead you to the page you see and the other will get you to the dashboard.  Depending on how you set it up, it could be `/Reports`, `/Reports_SSRS` or anything else you may have set it up as.

Comment: Thanks. @Steve-o169. To confirm the URL, go into the Reporting Services Configuration Manager. That will show you both URL's.